# How does os kernel keep track of the locks that user threads are waiting on?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I know that when a user thread acquires for a lock(like event, semaphore and so on), the kernel will change the thread's state to waiting so the thread will not be scheduled to run until the kernel finds that the lock is available.
My question is how does the kernel captures the state of these locks? By polling or notifying?

Answer (score 3):

By notifying. Before the thread goes to sleep, it adds itself to the wakeup list for whatever kernel object corresponds to the thing it's waiting for.

This works precisely the same way all other waits work. Say, for example, the process does a blocking read on a file and the process has to sleep until the read completes. Or say the process accesses some code that hasn't been read in from disk yet. In all of these cases, the process is added to the appropriate wakeup notification scheme when it puts itself to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know that the process is notified by the kernel.But what I want to know is how does the kernel not the user process know the timing that the lock is available.The example you given is disk read and I think this is accomplished by the hardware interrupt. But what about the locks supplied by os, like semaphone, event, mutex?Do they have something to do with the hardware?

Comment: @burning Same thing. There is no difference. Whatever kernel code unlocks whatever it is the thread is blocked on also checks the list of things to wake up when that thing is unlocked -- the very list the thread added itself to when it went to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is highly system specific and lock specific. For example, quality operating systems have lock management facilities that will detect deadlocks.

Some locks might be implemented as spin locks where there is no process hibernation and no operating system notification at all.

In the case where waiting suspends a process, all the operating system needs to keep track of is the lock itself. If a process releases the lock, the operating system can send a notification to all the waiting process—no poling necessary.